# google maps api getZoom() after zooming

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Small problem.

So, i'm working with the google maps api for a small project at my internship.

This is how I make my map.

```
function initMap() {
    window.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 12,
      center: {lat: 62.323907, lng: -150.109291},
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    });

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(62.281819, -150.287132),
        new google.maps.LatLng(62.400471, -150.005608));

    // The photograph is courtesy of the U.S. Geological Survey.
    var srcImage ='https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/';
    srcImage += 'examples/full/images/talkeetna.png';


    overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);

  }
```

The problem I have is the next: I want to determine the zoom, I tried this with:

```
var zoom = window.map.getZoom();
alert(zoom);
```

This works! But the only problem I have, this always shows me '12'. And I want to get the current zoom level, after zooming in or out and that doesn't seem to work, it always keeps displaying '12'. How can I fix this?

Comment: which version of google api are you using?

Comment: i'm using this as a guideline, not shure what version this is [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-hideshow)

Comment: seems to be version 3

Comment: Ivs cheked the example you provided and put a button for cheking the zoom level...seems ok... could you make fiddle with your code..so that I can debug...

Comment: add the code to the question or just copypaste it here?

Comment: The best way, if you can figure out how to do it, is to create a jsfiddle, this way we can test your code right away! Here is a very base map you can fork to create your own: http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/Lw6tF/ if that can help you get started!

Comment: Could not get it working with jsfiddle :/ so I pasted all my code (it's one html file with css and javascript inside) in pastebin [link](http://pastebin.com/XbAvi9T1)

Answer (score 2):

It is quite simple add a "zoom_changed" listener for your map and get the current zoom of the map

The code can be like

```
map.addListener("zoom_changed", function() {
    alert("Zoom :" + map.getZoom());
});
```

Comment: Thats Ok not a problem :)